# GMT cron expression for a PST based schedule?

Tags: cron, timezone-offset, gmt

I want to setup a cron schedule for running something every 30 minutes from 6:00am to 11:30pm daily, Pacific Standard Time. I'm setting this up on an AWS Lambda function, which works strictly with GMT.

I first tried an approximation, ignoring DST:
`0,30 0-7,14-23 * * *`

This gave a syntax error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra asterisk (*) or more specifically, you are missing a field in the statement.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html